# Django Models create a task for all users

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to build a webapp where the same task is given to all users, and when the users complete the task they can mark it as completed, to do so I added a 'status' bool that is set to true when the 'task' is not complete, and with a button the user can set it to false, the problem is that when I use a many-to-many field, if one user changes the 'status', it changes for everyone.

I also tried using a Foreignkey but when I use a Foreignkey I have to create a task for every user.

What I want is to create a task, assign it to all users, and then all the users can interact with the task without affecting what other users see.

These are the models that I created(it's in spanish):

```
class Usuario(AbstractUser):
    pass


class Tps(models.Model):

    users = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, on_delete=CASCADE)
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    TECNOLOGIA_DE_LA_FABRICACION = 'TDF'
    MANTENIMIENTO_Y_REPARACION_DE_EQUIPOS = 'MYRDE'
    MAQUINAS_ELECTRICAS_Y_ENSAYOS = 'MEYE'
    SEGURIDAD_E_HIGIENE_INDUSTRIAL = 'SEHI'
    LABORATORIO_DE_ENSAYOS_INDUSTRIALES = 'LDEI'
    INSTALACIONES_INDUSTRIALES = 'II'
    RELACIONES_HUMANAS = 'RH'
    TALLER_DE_ELECTROMECANICA = 'TE'
    ORGANIZACION_INDUSTRIAL = 'OI'
    INSTALACIONES_ELECTRICAS = 'IE'
    EDUCACION_FISICA = 'EF'
    EQUIPOS_Y_APARATOS_DE_MANIOBRA_Y_TRANSPORTE = 'EYADMYT'

    MATERIAS_CHOICES = [
        (TECNOLOGIA_DE_LA_FABRICACION, 'Tecnologia de la fabricación'),
        (MANTENIMIENTO_Y_REPARACION_DE_EQUIPOS, 'Mantenimiento y R de equipos'),
        (MAQUINAS_ELECTRICAS_Y_ENSAYOS, 'Máquinas eléctricas y ensayos'),
        (SEGURIDAD_E_HIGIENE_INDUSTRIAL, 'Seguridad e higiene industrial'),
        (LABORATORIO_DE_ENSAYOS_INDUSTRIALES,
         'Laboratorio de ensayos industriales'),
        (INSTALACIONES_INDUSTRIALES, 'Instalaciones industriales'),
        (RELACIONES_HUMANAS, 'Relaciones humanas'),
        (TALLER_DE_ELECTROMECANICA, 'Taller de electromecánica'),
        (ORGANIZACION_INDUSTRIAL, 'Organización industrial'),
        (INSTALACIONES_ELECTRICAS, 'Instalaciones eléctricas'),
        (EDUCACION_FISICA, 'Educacion fisica'),
        (EQUIPOS_Y_APARATOS_DE_MANIOBRA_Y_TRANSPORTE,
         'Equipos y aparatos de maniobra y transporte')
    ]
    materia = models.CharField(
        max_length=8, choices=MATERIAS_CHOICES, default=None)

    fecha_actual = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    fecha_entrega = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)

    material = models.URLField()
    consignas = models.URLField()

    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titulo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use an intermediate table and make the relationship with the `through` attribute, so you could make a table like this:

```py
class Tps(models.Model):
    users = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, on_delete=CASCADE, through='TaskDone')

class TaskDone(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tps = models.ForeignKey(Tps, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Comment: I tried it, but the problem is that i still need to create a new 'TaskDone' object for every user, the problem about this is that it gets repetitive having to create the TaskDone for each user and Task over and over, is there a way to create a 'TaskDone' for each user automatically? or maybe select all users and then create the 'TaskDone' for each one of them?

Comment: If I get what you want them: When you create a task you assign a set of users? You could override the save() method or use a signal (I would go for the save method) so when task is saved create a for loop that creates a TaskDone for every user in your task users and assign each TaskDone with the current user in the the loop and the self instance as the task.

Comment: It worked! :) , i did not modify the save() method but i used a post_save.connect that creates the 'Taskdone' when 'Tps' is saved, thank you so much!